# CiviDiscount for Membership

Tags: civimember, cividiscount

I created a discount for a specific membership level, but a discount field is not showing up on the membership page.  CiviDiscount is enabled and has worked in the past with event registration.  When creating the new discount, I specified the membership type (annual) in the 'Discounts for Memberships' box. Do I have to specify a price set? If so, how do I do that? Nothing I type is accepted.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve:  Do you want to create a code to discount the price of an annual membership?  Or do you want those who have annual membership to get a discount on event registrations?  Or something else??

Comment: I want to add a code to discount the price of an annual membership.

Comment: BTW, I'm using Civi version  4.7.29  and CiviDiscount version  3.3.

Answer (score 1):

If CiviDiscount is enabled, you should see the discount box at the top of the membership page even if you don't have any discounts configured.  The position isn't great and can be missed if someone is expecting to see it near the amount.
[image]

You don't need to use price sets.

If you're quick, you can see an example at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/cividiscount but it is regularly reset.

I noticed though that the discount is not being applied correctly, so I have created a ticket for that.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help......I'm using Wordpress. Maybe there's something different with Wordpress? CiviDiscount is enabled, but I do not get a discount box at the top of the membership form.